# drive strength of OCXO

Tags: crystal

I am trying to find the drive level of an OCXO. The OCXO I am using is the [OCXO](http://www.abracon.com/Precisiontiming/AOCJY.pdf).
I am trying to find the max drive strength. I find only the minimum peak power in dBm. The screen shot is as shown below -

[image: Peak power]

Now, how ca I find the max or peak power ?

Comment: The minimum available power is 2dBm into 50 ohms. That is the maximum you can expect with 100% confidence.

Comment: So the max is not declared and cannot be calculated mathematically as well.

Comment: I would guess you could safely assume it wouldn't exceed the supply voltage- but that's a big difference from the 281mV guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum power would presumably be a rail-to-rail swing of the output voltage into 50Ω. 3.3 V<sub>P-P</sub> = 1.167 V<sub>RMS</sub>, and this represents

$$\frac{(1.167 V)^2}{50 \Omega} = 27.2 mW$$

or

$$10 \log(27.2) = +14.35 \text { dBm}$$

This is probably overly optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

+2dBm is 1.6 milliwatts, so 1.6 milliwatts into 50 Ω is:

$$ E = \sqrt{PR} =  \sqrt{0.0016W \times 50 \Omega} \approx 0.282 \text { volts RMS} $$

Comment: Thank you sir. But there is no way I can calculate the max drive strength,right ?

Comment: @Board-Man: I'm confused... What do you mean by "max drive strength"?

Comment: What you have shown makes sense and is def the power value that I seek. But it is the minimum power. What about the maximum value. There is no drive strength ? I assumed drive strength is an function of the power given by the dbm peak power.

Comment: Also, in the previous comment you mentioned the Voltage in RMS value. Why is the voltage in rms. So suppose I want to find max output power 
Voh = Squareroot(Power)*R.

R = 50Ohms and Voh = max of 3.3(as the supply is 3.3).
So, I get power = approx 4mW.

Comment: @Board-Man: You're right, and if you need to know the maximum power out an email or a call to the manufacturer would probably get it for you.

Comment: @Board-Man: RMS??? [**check this out.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)